# can I set clip path externally for highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, invisible

Can I set clip path externally for any high chart?I am using most recent version of Highchart and I came across a bug of Highchart(Series getting invisible when chart is re-size)this will be fixed in next version of highchart. To resolve this issue I have a workaround for that i need to set clip path.So how I want to know how to set clip path through JQuery?

Comment: Can't you simple download fixed version from here: http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js and store it locally?

Comment: @PawełFus actually problem is with this release only(v4.0.1) and they will fix it in next release.

Comment: If that's already fixed, then use github version - it's upcoming 4.0.2 release. Anyway, if you want to create workaround, just find clippath in DOM and change it's width and height.